# Sending a message between two Java components

Tags: java, messaging

I have a question about messaging systems.
There are two Java applications - A and B. A works constantly and checks the resource. In some cases it need to notifiy B to start. It seems that there is no need to enlarge this messaging later: there will be always two components.

What is the most elegant way to implement it? JMS? Spring Integration somehow?
Another options?

Do I understand correctly that in any case B needs to busily wait?

Comment: There are too many options to mention here, I would use the one which seems simplest to implement.  B doesn't have to busy wait and might not even be running when not active. The simplest option is to put A and B in the same process and have one call the other with a method call.

Comment: If it needs to be two separate applications: You can touch a file in A and use a WatchService or a quartz-job in B...

Answer (score 1):

IMO it is better to use [**Apache active mq**](http://activemq.apache.org/) . It is open source and supports JMS 1.1 and J2EE 1.4.

As you are using two applications.You can add the message  from A to Active MQ Queue and B would be continuously checking the message queue. So once B receives a message you could perform the operations that you would require.

Comment: To setup and maintain at least one jms server for sending _a_ message, while it's only a notification, it doesn't have any contents and therefore doesn't need transaction management is quite the overkill. I would never suggest to go with one of the most complex solutions for such a simple problem...

Comment: as mentioned by the user-  In some cases it need to notify B to start. as we don't know about the conditions as when to start B, when B receives the message we can check with the contents and continue with the required operation.